# Стилизация радиокнопок CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите пожалуйста, как стилизовать радиокнопки подобным образом? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стилизуют label, а не сами радиокнопки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
input {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;   
}
 
input, label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}
 
label {
    position: relative;
}

input + label:before {
    content: 'RU';
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}
input:checked + label:before {
    background: #56CFD2;
    color: #fff;
    border-color:#3eb9bc;
}
```

```html
    <input name="select-1" id="mktoCheckbox_46078_0" type="radio" value="Checkbox 1" class="mktoField">
    <label for="mktoCheckbox_46078_0"></label>
    <input name="select-1" id="mktoCheckbox_46078_1" type="radio" value="Checkbox 2" class="mktoField">
    <label for="mktoCheckbox_46078_1"></label>
```

Ну, а там дальше как вам нужно стилизуйте.

Answer (score 1):

На базе ответа от **Oleksandr**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .c1{
                height:0px;
                margin:0;
                opacity:0;
                width:0px;
            }
            .l1{
                background-color:aqua;
                display:inline-block;
                font-size:15px;
                font-weight:bold;
                padding:10px;
            }
            .c1:checked + .l1{
               background-color:blue;
               color:white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='radio' name='r' id='r1' class='c1'><label for='r1' class='l1'>EN</label>
        <input type='radio' name='r' id='r2' class='c1'><label for='r2' class='l1'>FR</label>
        <input type='radio' name='r' id='r3' class='c1'><label for='r3' class='l1'>GM</label>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Основная идея та же, что у `Oleksand` и `DNS`. Мы подсвечиваем спан, если стоящий перед ним инпут чекнутый. Но в этом решении есть дополнительная идея. Каждый элемент имеет свою обертку в виде `label`. Это может быть удобным при работе с элементами.

И дополнительно скажу о минусе использования только CSS. При таком подходе очень важен порядок элементов. Если поменять `input` и `span` местами или поставить межу ними какой-нибудь блок, то всё сломается. Поэтому нужно быть осторожным.

```css
.lang {
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
.lang:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.lang input {
  display: none;
}
.lang span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  font: 14px/58px 'Helvetica',sans-serif;
  height: 60px;
  min-width: 58px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top: 2px solid #39739d;
  padding: 0 7px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.lang input:checked + span {
  background-color: #39739d;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<label class="lang">
  <input type="radio" name="lang" checked>
  <span>EN</span>
</label>
<label class="lang">
  <input type="radio" name="lang">
  <span>FR</span>
</label>
<label class="lang">
  <input type="radio" name="lang">
  <span>GM</span>
</label>
```